# Getting NameError while importing a module

Tags: python-3.x

```
import requests
import json


token= "12882xxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
class T_bot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.base= "https://api.telegram.org/bot{}/".format(token)
        self.sendurl= "https://api.telegram.org/bot{}/sendMessage".format(token)
        #self.data= {'chat_id':1067109380, 'text': 'Hi I hope you are doing fine' }

    def gett(self, offset=None):
        url= self.base+"getUpdates?timeout=100"
        if offset:
            url = url+"&offset={}".format(offset+1)
        a= requests.get(url)
        return a.json()

    def send(self, msg, chat_id):
        url= self.base+"sendMessage?chat_id={}&text={}".format(chat_id,msg)
        if msg is not None:
            requests.get(url)
```

when I'm importing the above code (bot.py)as:

```
from bot import T_bot

update_id= None

def make_reply(msg):
    reply= 'okay'
    return reply

update_id= None

while True:
    
    updates= T_bot.gett(self, offset= update_id)
    updates= updates["result"]
    if updates:
        for item in updates:
            update_id= item['update_id']
            try:
                message= item['message']['text']
            except:
                message= None
                fromm= item['message']['from']['id']
                reply= make_reply(message)
                T_bot.send(reply, fromm)
```

it is throwing a NameError when I'm running the main file above:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shivam\Desktop\pypy\server.py", line 13, in <module>
    updates= T_bot.gett(self, offset= update_id)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

I understand that I have to instantiate class first but how can I do it when I'm importing another module. somebody, please explain it!

Comment: `T_bot.gett(self, offset= update_id)` this is not how a class is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to instantiate the class first.

Ie.

```
from bot import T_bot

update_id = None


def make_reply(msg):
    reply = 'okay'
    return reply


update_id = None
instantiated_class = T_bot()
while True:

    updates = instantiated_class.gett(offset=update_id)
    updates = updates["result"]
    if updates:
        for item in updates:
            update_id = item['update_id']
            try:
                message = item['message']['text']
            except:
                message = None
                fromm = item['message']['from']['id']
                reply = make_reply(message)
                T_bot.send(reply, fromm)
```